# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `match.params` of type `object` supplied to `Page`, expected `string`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Getting below error in React App:
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `match.params` of type `object` supplied to `Page`, expected `string`.

Below is my code snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Page = ({ match }) => {
  const { id } = match.params;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page {id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

Page.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};
export default Page;
```

Can anyone suggest where i'm making mistake as the match.params is already mentioned as string type in PropType.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you call Page component and what are the props you passed to It? Pease share the code of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` from `react-router` props is an `object` and not a `string` and hence you should use it like `PropTypes.object` or specify the exact shape of it using `PropTypes.shape`

```
Page.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.object,
  }).isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Params is an object, so you have to change it to `PropTypes.object` or use proptypes with id like this

```
Page.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it is clear that `match.params` is not a string. It is an object type that you are passing from wherever you have called the `Page` component and you are using `id` as `match.params.id`.

```
const { id } = match.params;
```

Your `propTypes` should look like this:

```
Page.propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.string,
    }),
  }).isRequired,
};
```

This will remove the error that you are getting.